# Português residence

Tags: resident-permit, residency, residence-cards, portugal

Hi I'm from Algeria but I'm living in Portugal and I residance permit card of 1 year.
May I change it to the island one?
And which kind of documents that I need? 
Thank you

Comment: Island permit? Do you mean for Madeira or Azores or something else?